# How to call parts of same dash(plotly) app layout to various parts of the website

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, data-visualization, plotly-dash

Suppose I have a sample website like this

[image]

I'm trying to integrate UI with plots created in dash(plotly).

I wanted to know if it's possible to call plots of the same dash app layout to different parts of the webpage.

If not, then how to add same filter to multiple layouts. For example if I change something in the top left plot, then it should also be reflected in the bottom right plot.

I'm new to this, so would like to know any solution that might work i.e.

calling parts of the same layout or

creating multiple layouts and adding filters to the same.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, and it's certainly possible. [Here's](https://dash-gallery.plotly.host/dash-oil-and-gas/) an example. It's probably too broad for a question here, though.

Comment: Are these made on different layouts(the filter part and the graph part)? also can you share the source code for the same? Like how this has been done.

Comment: The source code is [available here](https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps/tree/master/apps/dash-oil-and-gas).